# Calculate current based on previous formula

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a scenario where the current column value is calculated based on the previous value calculated by the formula
The initial row of the group has no previous value so it will not consider.

Formula for loss= relase-withdraw-least(previous_row_loss,reverse)

Here below loss is the column I need to calculate.
[image]

I tried with the following query but not getting expected output. Can you please guide me here.

```
SELECT
pid,release,withdraw,reverse,
SUM(release - withdraw - LEAST( LAG(loss,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY pid)),reverse))  as loss 
FROM transactions
```

Comment: Do you have any column for ordering the rows as Database tables are unordered sets.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai- i have added fiscalperiod column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `MODEL` clause:

```sql
SELECT *  
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY pid, fiscalperiod) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
MODEL
  DIMENSION BY (rn)
  MEASURES (pid, fiscalperiod, release, withdraw, reverse, 0 AS loss)
  RULES (
    loss[1]    = release[1] - withdraw[1] - reverse[1],
    loss[rn>1] = release[cv()] - withdraw[cv()] - LEAST(reverse[cv()], loss[cv()-1])
                 + loss[cv()-1]
);
```

Or, probably, much less efficiently a recursive query:

```sql
WITH numbered_rows AS (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY pid, fiscalperiod) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
),
recursive_query (rn, pid, fiscalperiod, release, withdraw, reverse, loss) AS (
  SELECT rn,
         pid,
         fiscalperiod,
         release,
         withdraw,
         reverse,
         release - withdraw - reverse
  FROM   numbered_rows
  WHERE  rn = 1
UNION ALL
  SELECT n.rn,
         n.pid,
         n.fiscalperiod,
         n.release,
         n.withdraw,
         n.reverse,
         n.release - n.withdraw + GREATEST(r.loss - n.reverse, 0)
  FROM   numbered_rows n
         INNER JOIN recursive_query r
         ON (n.rn = r.rn + 1)
)
SELECT *
FROM   recursive_query;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (pid, fiscalperiod, release, withdraw, reverse) AS
SELECT 'A1', 2022001, 10, 10, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A1', 2022002, 20, 13,  2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A1', 2022003, 20, 20, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A2', 2022002, 15, 10, 13 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | RN | PID | FISCALPERIOD | RELEASE | WITHDRAW | REVERSE | LOSS |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | A1 | 2022001 | 10 | 10 | 10 | -10 |
> | 2 | A1 | 2022002 | 20 | 13 | 2 | 7 |
> | 3 | A1 | 2022003 | 20 | 20 | 10 | 0 |
> | 4 | A2 | 2022002 | 15 | 10 | 13 | 5 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c0a0640dea49e9608036baa8ddb87efe)*

Comment: Thank you very much . I will check this. Is Model clause is the only way to achieve this. Is it possible to use any windows functions? I am trying to use it also in other DB. so looking for the possible solution in other DB.

Comment: @Satheesh Added a recursive query that would also give the same output; however, my guess is that for a large data set that the `MODEL` clause will perform much better but you should profile that.